# このJQueryは何をやっているんでしょう？？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Webのパブリッシングフレームワークのカスタマイズをやっています．既存のコードを見ながらカスタマイズしてゆかなければならないんですが、JavaScript、JQuery、TypeScriptとも初心者でわからないことだらけです．

端的にいいますと以下のコードは何をやっているのかがよくわかりません．

```js
        if (totalPageNumber > 1) {
            // Add pagination widget
            $('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag({
                total: totalPageNumber,          // total pages
                page: pageToShow,            // default page
                maxVisible: 10,     // visible pagination
                leaps: false,         // next/prev leaps through maxVisible
                next: i18n.getLocalization("next.page"),
                prev: i18n.getLocalization("prev.page")
            }).on("page", function(event, num){
                util.debug("Display page with number: ", num);

                // Replace or add the page query
                var oldPage = util.getParameter("page");
                var oldQuery = window.location.search;
                var oldHref = window.location.href;
                var oldLocation = oldHref.substr(0, oldHref.indexOf(oldQuery));

                var newQuery = "";
                if (oldPage == undefined || oldPage == "undefined" || oldPage == "") {
                    newQuery = oldQuery + "&page=" + num;
                } else {
                    var re = new RegExp("(\\?|&)page\=" + oldPage);
                    newQuery = oldQuery.replace(re, "$1page="+num);
                }

                window.history.pushState("searchPage" + num, document.title, oldLocation + newQuery);

                displayPageResults(num);
                /*$("#content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
                 // ... after content load -> change total to 10
                 $(this).bootpag({total: 10, maxVisible: 10});*/
            });
```

の、`$('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag`から `}).on`の直前まで．

質問は以下です．

1. `$('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag` は@id="wh-search-pagination"の要素の下位の@class="bootpag"の要素選択でいいんでしょうか？
2. ではそのあとの

   ```
              page: pageToShow,            // default page
              maxVisible: 10,     // visible pagination
              leaps: false,         // next/prev leaps through maxVisible
              next: i18n.getLocalization("next.page"),
              prev: i18n.getLocalization("prev.page")
   ```

   は何者なんでしょうか？属性設定ですか？でもこんな属性ってHTMLにはないですよね？？

これから後は参考情報です、

実はこのフレームワークのカスタマイズしていないものは結構よく使われていて以下で見られます．

https://www.ixiasoft.com/documentation/IXIASOFT_CCMS/6.3/User_Guides_Writer_DRM/ja/search.html?searchQuery=CCMS

ここでF12でElementを押して見ますと、@id="wh-search-pagination"の個所がわかります、ページ下部の検索結果のページ数の表示欄です．

でも`<div id="wh-search-pagination">` の下位の `<ul class="pagination boottag">` を見ても、特別な属性設定されているようには見えません．

```html
    <div id="wh-search-pagination" class="wh-search-pagination col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <ul class="pagination bootpag">
        <li data-lp="1" class="prev disabled" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">前へ</a></li>
        <li data-lp="1" tabindex="-1" class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);">1</a></li>
        <li data-lp="2" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">2</a></li>
        <li data-lp="3" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">3</a></li>
        <li data-lp="4" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">4</a></li>
        <li data-lp="5" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">5</a></li>
        <li data-lp="6" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">6</a></li>
        <li data-lp="7" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">7</a></li>
        <li data-lp="8" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">8</a></li>
        <li data-lp="2" class="next" tabindex="-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">次へ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

以上 ぶしつけな質問ですみませんがよろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: bootpagで検索するとこういう[ライブラリ](https://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/)がhitしましたが、こちらのサイトは確認済みですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so 速攻でありがとうございます．まさにご指摘のライブラリのための設定ですね．その旨回答ください．acceptいたします．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bootpag-dynamic pagination jQuery plugin](https://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/)と呼ばれる
動的なページネーションを作成するためのjQueryプラグインのようです。

ほとんどのjQueryもしくはjQueryプラグインは

```
$(selector).メソッド()
```

という形をとっているため、この形のものが出てきたら
メソッド名で検索するかインストールしているプラグインをソース内で検索できれば、
どのような機能かプラグインを利用しているか判別できると思います。